Merge and sum stdclass arrays
Lets say i have two arrays:
1:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 12e3b273-ef84-4960-9f81-16cc35e69a58
            [sum] => 10
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 345265aa-5f85-405d-b256-9f2cc706d222
            [sum] => 20
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 8650b97e-f7c0-4d4c-a065-a082bd4fdbce
            [sum] => 30
        )
)

2:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 6be4da35-f0d0-4b24-99ed-ad06b95354ce
            [sum] => 200
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 8650b97e-f7c0-4d4c-a065-a082bd4fdbce
            [sum] => 100
        )
)

How to merge them and sum value of "sum" if it excist in first array?
Final array should look like:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 12e3b273-ef84-4960-9f81-16cc35e69a58
            [sum] => 10
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 345265aa-5f85-405d-b256-9f2cc706d222
            [sum] => 20
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 8650b97e-f7c0-4d4c-a065-a082bd4fdbce
            [sum] => 130 (100 + 30)
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object (added because it doesn´t excist in first array)
        (
            [uuid] => 6be4da35-f0d0-4b24-99ed-ad06b95354ce
            [sum] => 200
        )
)

Have no clue where to start.

Have you tried anything, like a foreach loop maybe?

Yes i have tried foreach on array 1 and then another foreach inside that foreach on array 2 but then everything gets added 2 times. Must be an easier way.

"but then everything gets added 2 times" - Then you must be doing something wrong. If you add your attempt, including the output you expect and what you actually get, we're glad to help you sort it out. That's what a minimal, reproducible example is.

Does this answer your question? Merge JavaScript objects in array with same key

It is a simple task of iterating over your arrays and checking the value. I composed two simple function to help with that. The first one checks the first array and retuns an index of the object with same UUID.
function getIndex(array $array1, stdClass $object): ?string
{
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->uuid === $object->uuid) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}

The second function is the algorithm to merge and sum objects in those arrays. Beware that this function mutates the first array. If this is not the intended behavior, you could store the results in another array created in the function and return the array, instead of mutating the first one.
function mergeAndSum(array &$array1, array $array2): void
{
    foreach ($array2 as $object) {
        $key = getIndex($array1, $object);
        
        if ($key !== null) {
            $array1[$key]->sum += $object->sum;
        } else {
            $array1[] = $object;
        }
    }
}

When calling these function like that, it produces the output you desired.
$array1 = [
    (object) [ 
        'uuid' => '12e3b273-ef84-4960-9f81-16cc35e69a58',
        'sum' => 10 
    ],  
    (object) [ 
        'uuid' => '345265aa-5f85-405d-b256-9f2cc706d222',
        'sum' => 20 
    ],
    (object) [ 
        'uuid' => '8650b97e-f7c0-4d4c-a065-a082bd4fdbce',
        'sum' => 30 
    ],
];

$array2 = [
    (object) [ 
        'uuid' => '6be4da35-f0d0-4b24-99ed-ad06b95354ce',
        'sum' => 200, 
    ],  
    (object) [ 
        'uuid' => '8650b97e-f7c0-4d4c-a065-a082bd4fdbce',
        'sum' => 100,
    ],
];


mergeAndSum($array1, $array2);

print_r($array1);

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 12e3b273-ef84-4960-9f81-16cc35e69a58
            [sum] => 10
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 345265aa-5f85-405d-b256-9f2cc706d222
            [sum] => 20
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 8650b97e-f7c0-4d4c-a065-a082bd4fdbce
            [sum] => 130
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uuid] => 6be4da35-f0d0-4b24-99ed-ad06b95354ce
            [sum] => 200
        )

)

Just a disclaimer - this algorithm could be slow if you try to sum large numbers of these objects. If the objects are unique, you could index them in an associative array by their UUID and instead of iterating over the whole array in getIndex you could check if the element is in the array using isset or array_key_exists.

You have nested loops here which won't perform well as the array sizes increase. The OP didn't say what array sizes need to be handled, but it can be done much more efficiently for large arrays.

As I said in my disclaimer. It depends on how the OP retrieves the data. It would be much more efficient to index the array by the UUID and perform a simple check whether or not the key is in the array. But not knowing the exact specifics, it is hard to provide an optimal solution :/
